# C# Convert ArrayList to List of string?

Tags: c#, .net, string, list, arraylist

I have an `ArrayList`, need to add the items of ArrayList into a List of string. I tried the following:

```
listString.AddRange(new List<string>((string[])this.arrayList.ToArray()))
```

But this gives an exception of

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Object[]' to type 'System.String[]'

Please note :; I can't use .Cast as I am working in framework `4.0`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `ToArray(typeof(string))` to create an Array and then cast it to a more specific array type `string[]` before adding it to the variable of type `List<string>`

```
listString.AddRange((string[])this.arrayList.ToArray(typeof(string)));
```

Comment: That actually worked. That was a great help. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

You can try the below code as follows:

```
ArrayList al = new ArrayList();
 List<string> lst = new List<string>();
 foreach (string l in al)
 {
    lst.Add(l);
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

LINQ to objects has a Cast method, which returns an IEnumerable of T where all the types have been cast (assuming the cast is valid) , so i'd suggest:

```
this.ArrayList.Cast<string>().ToList();
```

or, if your listString is already existing:

```
listString.AddRange(this.ArrayList.Cast<string>());
```

Comment: Yes, i did. But check [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406(v=vs.100).aspx) on Cast(). It is supported since 3.5

Answer (score 1):

You have to convert each elements of the array list into a string to add them in a List of strings. Better option for doing this is like the following:

```
 listString.AddRange(arrayList.ToArray().Select(x => x.ToString()).ToList());
```

Comment: I am not able to use Select/ Cast/ ToList(). There isn't any definition for these all in ArrayList. However, the answer given by Svein Fidjestøl worked.

Comment: To make it work you have to add `using System.Linq;` to the using section

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me, the safest way:

```
listString.AddRange(arrayList.ToArray().Select(e => e.ToString()));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList arrayList = new ArrayList {"A","B","C" };
List<string> listString = new List<string>();  
foreach (string item in arrayList)
{
    listString.Add(item);
}
var data = listString;
```

Answer (score -4):

Try to understand below code : this code solve problem.

```
ArrayList myAL = new ArrayList(); 
myAL.Add( "The" );
myAL.Add( "quick" );    
myAL.Add( "brown" ); 
myAL.Add( "fox" ); 

// Creates and initializes a new Queue.
Queue myQueue = new Queue();
myQueue.Enqueue( "jumped" ); 
myQueue.Enqueue( "over" ); 

// Displays the ArrayList and the Queue.  
Console.WriteLine( "The ArrayList initially contains the following:" );
PrintValues( myAL, '\t' );
Console.WriteLine( "The Queue initially contains the following:" ); 
PrintValues( myQueue, '\t' ); 

// Copies the Queue elements to the end of the ArrayList. 
myAL.AddRange( myQueue );
```

Comment: Indeed this is hard to understand. Not sure why one would spend time to  "try to understand" it...